# Finding missing row of $3\times 3$ matrix given desired eigenvalues of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given matrix

$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  x & y & z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to put in the final row that makes it so the eigenvalues of the matrix are $1,2,3$.

I know that the trace of C should equal the sum of the eigenvalues. Therefore
$$z=6$$
I know that the determinant must be equal the the eigenvalues multiplied together. $\text{Det}(C) = x$. So now I know
$$x = 6xy \implies y = 1/6$$

I'm left with $x$ being anything but clearly it can't be anything... What's the appropriate way to solve for the last variable?

Comment: $x = 6xy$, why? why are z, x and y the eigenvalues? You are mixing up things. You can't call the eigenvalues and the elements the same variable names unless you have proven they are the same thing.

Comment: Ahhhh you’re right. Hmmm

Answer (score 3):

$C$ is the transpose of a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Therefore, the last row consists of the negative coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. The characteristic polynomial is
$$
\chi(t) = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)(t-\lambda_3)
= (t-1)(t-2)(t-3) = t^3-6t^2+11t-6
$$
from which we can derive $x=6,$ $y=-11$ and $z=6.$

Answer (score 2):

Two of your observations are correct, but you mix up elements and eigenvalues in some places which gives some faulty equations.

$z=e_1+e_2+e_3=1+2+3=6$ equals trace is a reasonable observation

$x=det = e_1\cdot e_2\cdot e_3=1\cdot 2 \cdot 3=6$ also.

We have only $y$ left to determine. I think some relatively straight forward brute force calculation should be able to find $y$ if it exists.

Let us look at the easiest eigenvalue $= 1$. It means there exists 1 non-zero vector that will be taken to the 0 vector by the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&-1&1\\6&y&5\end{bmatrix}$$

Let's assume it is $[a,b,c]^T$

now $[b-a,c-b,6a+yb+5c]=[0,0,0]$

Already the first two equations say $b=a, c=b$ which tells us that they must all be the same.

$6+y+5=0$ gives $y = -11$.

We can verify that it works. For example in Gnu Octave with the code:

```
eig([0,1,0;0,0,1;6,-11,6])'
```

gives us $[1,2,3]$.

But it is of course a good exercise to do it by hand.

Comment: I like this answer! It uses a lot of logic that I'm comfortable with. I solved using eigenvalue 2 to verify I actually understood your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need $C - \lambda I$ to be singular for $\lambda = 1,2,3$. Just compute these matrices with $z=6$ and $y = 1/6$ and one of them should give you a constraint on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. It has three terms and you may notice that two of the coefficients are the trace and the determinant (up to some sign). The third coefficient equals 1*2 + 2*3 + 3*1 or in general the sum of the three products of three eigenvalues.

Comment: I've never used characteristic polynomials before, I'm doing some reading online and it seems take a diagonal matrix of ts and subtract your matrix from it. When I do that and take the determinant, I have $t(t(t-6)-1/6+x$ but I don't know what to do with the $t$ and I'm not sure what it's supposed to set equal to... Can you help me out a bit further?

Comment: @financial_physician The roots of the characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues. That's what characteristic polynomials are designed for. Really, I find it a bit strange that you've been introduced to eigenvalues and how they relate to trace and determinant, yet you have not come across the characteristic polynomial. That's... unconventional.

Comment: @Arthur does a characteristic polynomial have more properties than just the definition? Or is the only thing cool about them that matrices with the same eigenvalues have the same characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @financial_physician There are more properties to it. For instance, the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) says that if you insert a matrix into its own characteristic polynomial, and evaluate, the result is the zero matrix.